# JQuery Value vs Reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to progressively enhance a div element containing an a tag, so that the content of the div is updated and the click event of the div opens the href of the (before Javascript modification), a.

I have the following code:

```
$("div")
    .click(function(){
        window.open($("div a").attr("href"));
    })
    .html("&gt;");

<div>Some text and <a href="link.html">a link</a></div>
```

The problem is, when the click event happens, the content of the `<div>` has already been updated and so the href attribute is no longer valid.

Any assistance on how I would write this so the url is remembered would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
$("div").each(function () {
    var url = $('a', this).attr('href');
    $(this).click(function () { window.open(url); }).html("&gt;");
});
```

If there is only one `div`, you can skip the `.each` and simply save the `href` value into a variable before replacing the content. Or use a closure:

```
$("div")
    .click((function (url) {
        return function () { window.open(url); };
    })($("div a").attr('href')))
    .html("&gt;");
```